# Firebase/Unity Google Authentication Pop Up Missing

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

My code for Google Authentication works fine but the trouble is that once an email is selected, it does not display the pop-up again. It automatically selects the previous selected Gmail account even after signing out.

How do I always display the pop-up box for sign-in?

```
   public void GoogleSignInClick()
    {
        configuration = new GoogleSignInConfiguration { WebClientId = GoogleWebAPI, RequestIdToken = true };
        if (GoogleSignIn.Configuration == null)
        {
            GoogleSignIn.Configuration = configuration;
            GoogleSignIn.Configuration.UseGameSignIn = false;
        }
        GoogleSignIn.Configuration.RequestIdToken = true;

        GoogleSignIn.Configuration.RequestEmail = true;

        GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignIn().ContinueWith(OnGoogleAuthenticatedFinished);

    }
```

Comment: Can you publish all class code?